# Seaborn set figsize=(x,y) error and warning about tight_layout "tight_layout cannot make axes height small enough to accommodate all axes decorations"

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a 10-plot FacetGrid chart in Seaborn with slightly overlapping plots. I want to change the size of the overall figure.  When I use g.fig.subplots(figsize=(12,12)) in the code below, I get an error message `TypeError: subplots() got an unexpected keyword argument 'size'`.

Also, I get a warning about `UserWarning: Tight layout not applied. tight_layout cannot make axes height small enough to accommodate all axes decorations self.fig.tight_layout()`

I don't see anywhere in my code where tight_layout() is referenced.  It is embedded in the module: `C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\axisgrid.py:848`.  I don't want to muck around in a site packages module.  How do I adjust parameters so that I don't get this warning.

I want to fix the problem, not just suppress this warning.  I don't know enough about the internals of Seaborn and Matplotlib to fix this error and get rid of the warning.

I tried adding `g.fig.subplots(figsize=(12,12))` to change the figure size.  Apparently FacetGrid plots are not contained in a figure, or I am referencing the figure bounding box object incorrectly.

```
"""
FacetGrid Plot Showing Overlapping Distributions (Densities) Offset by ('ridge plot')
====================================
"""
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="white", rc={"axes.facecolor": (0, 0, 0, 0)})

# Create some random distribution data and labels, and store them in a dataframe
rs = np.random.RandomState(1979)
x = rs.randn(500)
g = np.tile(list("ABCDEFGHIJ"), 50)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=x, g=g))
m = df.g.map(ord)
df["x"] += m

# Initialize the FacetGrid chart object
pal = sns.cubehelix_palette(10, rot=-.25, light=.7)
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="g", hue="g", aspect=15, height=.5, palette=pal)

# Draw the densities in a few steps
g.map(sns.kdeplot, "x", clip_on=False, shade=True, alpha=1, lw=1.5, bw=.2)
g.map(sns.kdeplot, "x", clip_on=False, color="w", lw=2, bw=.2)
g.map(plt.axhline, y=0, lw=2, clip_on=False)


# Define and use a simple function to label the plot in axes coordinates
def label(x, color, label):
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.text(0, .2, label, fontweight="bold", color=color,
            ha="left", va="center", transform=ax.transAxes)

# Use ``map()`` to calculate the label positions
g.map(label, "x")

# Set the subplots to overlap slightly on their vertical direction
g.fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=-.3)

# Remove axes details that don't play well with overlap
g.set_titles("")
g.set(yticks=[])
g.despine(bottom=True, left=True)
g.fig.subplots(figsize=(12,12))  # Don't know how to change figure size for a set of overlapping Seaborn plots
```

I get the following warning, followed by the error message after that, and then the FacetedGrid plot is displayed without changing its size.

```
  self.fig.tight_layout()
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\axisgrid.py:848: UserWarning: Tight layout not applied. tight_layout cannot make axes height small enough to accommodate all axes decorations
  self.fig.tight_layout()
C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\seaborn\axisgrid.py:848: UserWarning: Tight layout not applied. tight_layout cannot make axes height small enough to accommodate all axes decorations
  self.fig.tight_layout()
```

---

```
<ipython-input-25-a661dbef6e83> in <module>
     43 g.set(yticks=[])
     44 g.despine(bottom=True, left=True)
---> 45 g.fig.subplots(size=(12,12))  # Don't know how to change figure size for a set of overlapping Seaborn plots

TypeError: subplots() got an unexpected keyword argument 'size'
```

#############

After all comments were integrated, here's the source code for a good, tight plot without warnings or errors:

```
`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
""" Created on Mon Jun 24 12:21:40 2019 @author: rlysak01 
FacetGrid Plot Showing Overlapping Distributions (Densities) Offset by ('ridge plot')
"""
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sns.set(style="white", rc={"axes.facecolor": (0, 0, 0, 0)})

# Create some random distribution data and labels, and store them in a dataframe
rs = np.random.RandomState(1979)
x = rs.randn(500)
g = np.tile(list("ABCDEFGHIJ"), 50)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=x, g=g))
m = df.g.map(ord)
df["x"] += m

# Initialize the FacetGrid chart object
pal = sns.cubehelix_palette(10, rot=-.25, light=.7)
# g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="g", hue="g", aspect=6, height=1.0, palette=pal)
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="g", hue="g", palette=pal)

''' Alternatively set figsize using the following 2 parameters.'''
g.fig.set_figheight(5.5)
g.fig.set_figwidth(7)
# or use plt.gcf().set_size_inches(12, 12)

# Draw the densities in a few steps
g.map(sns.kdeplot, "x", clip_on=False, shade=True, alpha=1, lw=1.5, bw=.2)
g.map(sns.kdeplot, "x", clip_on=False, color="w", lw=2, bw=.2)
g.map(plt.axhline, y=0, lw=2, clip_on=False)

# Define and use a simple function to label the plot in axes coordinates
# Values x,y in ax.text(x,y, ...) controls the x,y offset from the x axis.
def label(x, color, label):
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.text(0, .2, label, fontweight="bold", color=color,
            ha="left", va="center", transform=ax.transAxes)

# Use ``map()`` to calculate the label positions
g.map(label, "x")

# Set the subplots to overlap slightly on their vertical direction
g.fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=-0.5)

# Remove axes details that don't play well with overlap
g.set_titles("")
g.set(yticks=[])
g.despine(bottom=True, left=True)
`
```

Comment: Thanks for the coaching on accepting answers properly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found a solution where you can set the height and the width separately as

```
g.fig.set_figheight(12)
g.fig.set_figwidth(12)
```

Alternatively, you can try setting the size of the current  figure as

```
g.despine(bottom=True, left=True)
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(12, 12)
```

**Sample output for a (5,5) size using the above line**

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  The top solution works well.  When working in inches, there is a limitation of a 5.5" x 1.5" in order to not generate errors.  The practical minimum size plot is about 6" for a 2" size plot that makes the plot usable.

Comment: I did a little more testing.  The 5.5" vertical setting is usable.  I tested different width settings and it displays without warning anywhere from ~ 1 inch wide (totally impractical) through a screen width limit of 22+ inches.

Comment: I did a little more testing the best settings to control figure usability are : `g.fig.set_figheight(5.5)
g.fig.set_figwidth(6)`    Eliminate aspect=6 and height=1.0 in sns.FacetGrid() so that it looks like this:  g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="g", hue="g", palette=pal)` because they are redundant and get overwritten anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively to Sheldore's answer, the dimensions of a FacetGrid are controlled by:

> height : scalar, optional
>
> ```
> Height (in inches) of each facet. See also: aspect.
> ```
>
> aspect : scalar, optional
>
> ```
> Aspect ratio of each facet, so that aspect * height gives the width of each facet in inches.
> ```

Therefore, If you would like to have a final figure of size 12x12 in, and you have 10 subplots, you need `height = 12/10 = 1.2` and `width = aspect * height`, or `aspect = width/height = 12/1.2 = 10`

You thus need to create your FacetGrid using:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row="g", hue="g", aspect=10, height=1.2, palette=pal)
```

Comment: This explains the confusing behavior better than only varying height and width.  Aspect ratio, height, spacing between subplots (param in "g.fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=-1.5)" ) and individual subplot label size all interact to control proper overlap and display.  Increasing hspace parameter (in code line: g.fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=-.5) to bigger than 1, the subplots flip vertically and the subplots start getting smaller and smaller.  There is a subtle interplay between these parameters to make plots look right and be useful.  Using aspect=6 and height=1.0 are good with hspace = -0.5.